# How is squashing different from just taking the last commit?

Tags: git

Explanations of squashing usually say the process incorporates the changes of a commit into previous commit(s), resulting in a single commit.

However, I am very confused about what this is actually supposed to mean, because commits do not represent deltas but complete versions of the project.

Let's say I have four commits

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D
```

and I check out `D` and interactively rebase on `A`, squashing `B`, `C`, and `D` into a single commit `BCD`.

The result is:

```
A <-- BCD
```

My question is how the tree above is different from

```
A <-- D
```

because no matter what examples I tried the working directory of `BCD` always looked like just `D`. I would be grateful for an example where `A <-- BCD` and `A <-- D` differ.

---

**CLARIFICATION**

It seems my question caused some confusion, so here is an alternative wording:

If I opened commit `D` in the .git/objects folder with an editor and changed the parent pointer from `C` to `A`, and then delete the commits `B` and `C` from the .git/objects folder, I would get

```
A <-- D
```

Question: is the tree above identical to `A <-- BCD`, the tree I get by squashing `B`, `C` and `D` in an interactive rebase?

(And in case the trees are identical, would I have arrived at yet the same result by picking "drop" for `B` and `C` in the interactive rebase instead of using squashing?)

Comment: "*commits do not represent deltas but complete versions of the project.*" commits **are** just deltas. Let's say commit A adds a file, commit B adds few lines in the file, commit C then modifies one of those lines. If you just take commit C you'll see a merge conflict because according to Git, you're making a modification of a line that it doesn't know it exists in a file it doesn't know it exists. If you squash ABC then you'd get one commit that adds a file with the modified content as if that's the only thing that happened.

Comment: @VLAZ No. Commits store tree objects which contain pointers to all other trees and blobs needed to create the entire working directory. They are not deltas.

Comment: They are treated as deltas for all intents and purposes when determining the history and conflicts. The entire model is built on sequential changes, which is why the parent is part of the identity of the commit.

Comment: You can use that as you mental model but it does not answer the question in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [matt said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62748893/1256452), the trick here is that most of the commands we use for *managing* the commits wind up turning the snapshots into change-sets.  When they deal with commits as change-sets they really do have to do this sort of replaying, even though the smart way (as noted below) wouldn't.

#### Longer

Remember that every commit has a unique hash ID, which will only ever refer to *that particular* commit.  No part of any commit can ever be changed, including the back-pointer to its parent: if we try to change any part of any commit, we end up with a new, different commit, with a new, unique hash ID.  So, given the original sequence:

> ```
> A <-B <-C <-D   <--branchname
> ```

we're going to end up with:

```
  B <-C <-D   [abandoned]
 /
A <-E   <--branchname
```

no matter what else happens.  We can have `E` be the equivalent of the squash of `BCD`, or we can have `E` be different in some way: perhaps we retain `D`'s *tree* but use a different *commit message* than any of `B`, `C`, or `D`; and of course `E` points directly back to `A`, which is unlike `C` and `D`.

Using `git rebase -i` and replacing two `pick`s with `squash`es uses a somewhat inefficient method of arriving at exactly that situation: it builds up, as a temporary commit that gets shoved aside, a combined `BC` commit with a combined message, and then readies (but doesn't quite commit yet) a combined `BCD` commit—one whose tree will match that of commit `D`—and a combined message.  It then invokes your editor on the combined message.

If we replace the two `pick`s with `fixup`s, Git still builds the combined `BC` commit but uses `B`'s message, then makes as our `E` commit the combined `BCD` commit using `B`'s message.

The *efficient* way to handle this would be to make a single `E` commit that uses `D`'s tree and a message.  Git could be taught to do this, but that's a special case that just falls out of the easier add-one-at-a-time method.  (It's possible that since the rewrite of rebase into C, Git actually *has* been taught to do this—I have not looked into the inner workings lately; the last time I did, the shell script based rebase definitely made separate commits.)

You can also run `git merge --squash`, which ends up doing this more cleverly, but to do that you need to assign a branch name to point to commit `A`:

```
A   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D   <-- branch2
```

With `branch1` checked out as shown, running `git merge --squash branch2 && git commit` will produce:

```
A---------E   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D   <-- branch2
```

without the excess compute-work that the rebase method might use.  But computer time is usually pretty cheap, and this requires more human-time to set up the multiple branch names.  (You need the `&& git commit` because `--squash` always turns on `--no-commit`.)

Compare the squash-merge result to a regular merge:

```
A---------E   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
 \       /
  B--C--D   <-- branch2
```

The difference is that a regular merge records *two* parents for new commit `E`, and a squash-merge doesn't.  The lack of extra compute work occurs because there is no commit after `A`; Git realizes that moving from `A` to `D` is a *fast forward* operation, i.e., that it means *just use `D`'s snapshot*.  Had we started with:

```
A--E--F   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D   <-- branch2
```

there would have been real work to do, for either squash-merge *or* real-merge, and Git would have done that work to produce new merge, or non-merge, commit `G`:

```
A--E--F---G   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
 \       ?
  B--C--D   <-- branch2
```

(where `?` means that there's an arrow back from `G` to `D` for the real-merge case, but not for the squash-merge case).

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you. So, in summary, my mental model of squashing was correct with respect to the content of the snapshots, but writing the result as `A <-- D` is incorrect because if you change any part of `D` (like its parent), `D` is not `D` anymore since its hash changes. Correct?

Comment: If you could clarify two things before I accept, please: 1. "perhaps we retain D's tree" <- why "perhaps"? 2. In my example, what's the difference between dropping `B` and `C` in an interactive rebase versus squashing `B`, `C` and `D` into `BCD`?

Comment: The "perhaps" is because we're building a new commit E, and we can make any changes we like: we can change the commit message, and/the date-and-time-stamps, *and* we can change the tree *if we want to* (D's tree, or not). And, if you drop B and C during an interactive rebase, you definitely won't retain D's tree: you will, in effect, apply D's change-set to A's content.  In more precise terms, Git will run its merge machinery, with C chosen as the merge base, and A and D as the `--ours` and `--theirs` commits respectively, as if you had done `git checkout A; git cherry-pick C`.

Comment: Got it! My problem was that I viewed commits as complete snapshots of the working tree (which is technically correct) but during a rebase they are "treated" (forgive the imprecise wording) as incremental changes - and that's why after dropping B and C the working directory is changed. This was confusing to me because if I went into the .git/objects folder and manually deleted B and C, I could still checkout D with no changes to the working directory.

Comment: Actually, commits are snapshots of Git's *index* (run `git ls-files --stage` to view, at a low level, what's in the index: beware, it's long and doesn't get fed through your pager) but if the index matches your work-tree, then it comes out to the same thing. Note that if you delete various objects directly from `.git/objects` you can damage your repository (fine for experimentation as Git can tolerate some amount of damage, but git fsck will complain for instance).

Answer (score 0):

> commits do not represent deltas but complete versions of the project

Yes, but diffs / patches do represent deltas. Squashing patches (replays) the diff A to D directly onto A and commits the result.

Merge, cherry pick, interactive rebase all involve diffs. Even though git does not *store* diffs, it *uses* diffs all the time.

> because no matter what examples I tried the working directory of BCD always looked like just D

Yes, and that’s exactly what’s desired and intended. The idea of squashing is to keep the same outcome but change the underlying commit history, e.g. two commits instead of four.

Comment: OK, but I'm still no wiser about what the difference between `A <-- BCD` and `A <-- D` is. I really need an example where these two trees are different.

Comment: But the whole purpose is for the resulting working trees not to be different. We’re trying to simplify the recorded history, not change the outcome. Two commits vs four commits are different histories. That is why we squashed. The end.

Comment: So there is no difference between squashing `B`, `C`, and `D` into a single commit `BCD` and just deleting `B` and `C` and setting the parent pointer of `D` to `A`?

Comment: How exactly would you do that second thing?

Comment: I'm sure it could be done by editing the commit object itself, but that's beside the point. My question is whether `A <-- BCD` is in any way different than `A <-- D`. The fact that I would not know how to create the second tree is irrelevant.

Comment: It's not beside the point. If you don't tell me in practical git terms what "just deleting B and C and setting the parent pointer of D to A" means, I don't know what we're comparing. I know what squash means, now tell me about the other thing.

Comment: OK, then suppose I edited the parent pointer in `D`'s commit object to `A` and deleted `C` and `B` from the objects folder. Would this give me the same result as `A <-- BCD` which I get with squashing?

Comment: OK hang on, I think I see what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No, sorry, I couldn’t make sense of the phrase “just deleting B and C and setting the parent pointer of D to A?”

Comment: I added a clarification to the question.

Comment: Not clearer, because the thing you describe is not a thing. The only real thing I can think of that is similar to what you said is interactive rebase where you _drop_ B and C vs interactive rebase where you _squash_ B and C together with D. And those clearly _do_ have different results.